# Accessing instance without self

Tags: python, twisted, self

I have the following code. In the dataReceived method, I am trying to access table, but I get an error. It works if I use self and do all of that, but I don't want to use self. Using self would not work for my purpose. How can I still gain access to table without using self?

Thanks!

```
class Table:
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []
        self.positions = []
        self.id = 0
        self.numberOfPlayers = 0

    def setID(self, _id):
        self.id = _id

    def setActivePlayer(self, player):
        player.countdown = 20
        while player.count > 0:
            print player.countdown
            time.sleep(1)
            player.countdown -= 1

            if player.countdown == 0:
                print "Out of time"

                moves.surrender(player)


class Socket(Protocol):
    table = Table()

    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "Clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]

            b = content.split(';')
            _UDID = b[0].replace('\n', '')

            if command == "Number_of_Players":
                if Socket.table.numberOfPlayers == 0:
                    msg = "%s:TableFound" % _UDID
                elif Socket.table.numberOfPlayers == 1:
                    msg = "%s:Table_Not_Found" % _UDID

        print msg

        for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message)

NUM_TABLES = 10

factories = [ ]
for i in range(0, NUM_TABLES):
    print i
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Socket
    factory.clients = []
    factories.append(factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(1025+i, factory)
    #print "Blackjack server started"

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `self`?  It works, and there's no reason we can see not to use it...

Comment: I am creating tables on different ports. When I use self, it seems each client still goes to the same port 1025, when the max number of people at a table is 1. That is why I don't want self. It seems it is creating a new table just for them. Right?

Comment: you are confused about how classes and objects work.  Don't try to avoid `self`.  Instead, straighten out your data model, and get your class implemented properly.

Comment: Then why do the clients all go to port 1025? The max number of players I set for a table was 1, if the table is full, the client requests the next available table, but still ends up at 1025.

Comment: Alec, there's not enough code here for us to diagnose this.

Comment: May I post the rest so you can help a little?

Comment: What is your class supposed to represent? What is `table` supposed to represent? How many `table`s are there supposed to be, and why? What is a `Table`?

Comment: Table acts as a Blackjack table. One table is assigned to one factory, and one factory is assigned to one port.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Socket.table` instead of `self.table` --

By the way: If the method is meant to be static, you can decorate it:

```
@staticmethod
def dataReceived(data):
```

[EDIT]: According to the comment section below...

If you want the exact oppssite, you may move the line `table = Table()` to a newly introduced constructor in the `Socket` class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.table = Table()
    return super(Socket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

After that, you can safely use `self.table` in the `dataReceived` method.
By the way, the `return super(Socket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` line just ensures that any constructor of any ancestor class (e.g. `Protocol`) is called also.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am creating tables on different ports. When I use self, it seems each client still goes to the same port 1025, when the max number of people at a table is 1. That is why I don't want self. It seems it is creating a new table just for them. Right?

Comment: Not sure whether I understood completely.. However, in the current state,`table` is a static property and shared between all instances of `Socket`. Maybe your problem would be solved by introducing a constructor that initializes a table for each instance?

Comment: How would I do that? When you say shared between all instances of Socket, do you mean that even on the other ports, they still access it? How is this fixed?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the intended *relationship between Tables and Sockets*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to assign a table to a socket, and a socket is assigned to a port.

Comment: Does every socket have its own table? Do the tables refer back to their corresponding sockets?

Comment: Every socket has its own table. The tables interact with the sockets by the sockets receiving the moves (hit, stand, etc), the table stores player positions, and the players themselves, and also the decks of cards.

Comment: My extension to the post is a simple constructor that's called implicitly in e.g. this line: `factory.protocol = Socket` -- it will ensure that each `Socket` has it's own `table`